# D3 x-axis not showing any data (datetime)

Tags: d3.js, asp.net-core-webapi, linechart

I am trying to generate a chart image in a WebAPI using Node Services and return it to whoever is calling it. I already managed to generate a pie diagram, but I am having difficulties generating a line chart. I get the following result:

[image]

JS Code:

```
// Include all modules we need
const svg2png = require("svg2png");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const d3 = require('d3');

// Define module
// callback - function to return data to caller
// options - chart options defined in controller
// data - chart data coming from controller
module.exports = function (callback, options, data) {

    // Create disconnected HTML DOM and attach it to D3
    var dom = new JSDOM('<html><body><div id="chart"></div></html>');
    dom.window.d3 = d3.select(dom.window.document);

    var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        width = options.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = options.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = dom.window.d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0])
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.value; }));
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.timeStamp; }));

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d['timeStamp']);
        })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d['value']); })
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 20)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Zeitstempel");

    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -40)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("°C");

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("d", line);

    // Convert SVG to PNG and return it to controller
    var svgText = dom.window.d3.select('#chart').html();
    svg2png(Buffer.from(svgText), { width: width, height: height })
        .then(buffer => 'data:image/png;base64,' + buffer.toString('base64'))
        .then(buffer => callback(null, buffer));
};
```

C# Code:

```
[HttpGet("charts/sensorvalues/{id}")]
public async Task<string> GetSensorValueChart(int id)
{
    var options = new { width = 360, height = 360 };
    var sensorValues = await _repository.GetSensorValueForDeliveryAsync(id);
    var data = sensorValues.Select(s => new { value = s.Value, timeStamp = s.TimeStamp });
    var chart = await _nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("SensorValues.js", options, data);
    return chart;
}
```

The y axis is showing correctly as my max value is about 200, but the x axis isn't showing at all. Can anybody help me out here?

EDIT: `TimeStamp` is a `DateTime` value

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little dated, but I just ran into the same issue. My axis ticks and label were rendering too far off-screen in the Y coordinate, so i just backed those down. Try subtracting the margins from the height, or adjusting the translate Y until you see it appear in your image:

```js
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - (margin.top + margin.bottom)})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Zeitstempel")
```